# Filter a list of dictionaries in Python based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would need to filter a list of dictionaries to only retain dictionaries which have a key called "children". Here is an example of list:

```
[{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]}, {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}, {u'id': 5649}]
```

And here is what I would need to obtain:

```
[{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]}, {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
dict((k, data[k]) for k in keys if k in data)
```

And what I obtain, which is not good:

```
[{u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]}, {u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}, {}]
```

Any clue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]}, {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}, {u'id': 5649}]
d = [k for k in l if 'children' in k]
print (d)
```

Outputs:

```
[{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]}, {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}]
```

---

The important line is the second line (`d = ...`). This is looping through each dictionary in the list and checking if there is a 'children' key. If there is, it is added to the list. If there is not, it's skipped.

Comment: Beat ya by 20 seconds. ;D But your answer contains a nice explanation. I'd upvote for that if I hadn't exhausted my daily vote limit.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function. It will take 2 arguments `filter(function, iterable)`. Only those values will be considered which the function returns.

```
a=[{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]},
   {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]},
   {u'id': 5649}]

print filter(lambda x: 'children' in x, a)
```

Output:

```
[{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]},
 {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}]
```

`filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]`

Answer (score 4):

How's this?

```
dict_list = [{u'id': 5650, u'children': [{u'id': 4635}]}, {u'id': 5648, u'children': [{u'id': 67}, {u'id': 77}]}, {u'id': 5649}]

filtered = [d for d in dict_list if 'children' in d]

print(filtered)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 5650, 'children': [{'id': 4635}]}, {'id': 5648, 'children': [{'id': 67}, {'id': 77}]}]
```